# React-Table Column Hiding

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I'm kind of new to React and Web development in general .

I have a scenario , to create a table in react , and create a box that would **enable to show/hide** **the columns** with it , and along with it a **select all checkbox** that would show or hide all columns **except** a **"NAME_ID"** column .
I am able to achieve the earlier part with with `useTable()` hook and  `column.getToggleHiddenProps()` method from destructured call of hook .

But I'm not able to achieve the second part , I do know that we have `getToggleHideAllColumnsProps()` but that won't allow me to except the required **NAME_ID** column .

Any help or suggestions would be great !!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to accomplish this. I wish this was a boolean to pass to the Columns object, but we take what we can get.

[I forked the original Hidden Columns sandbox as a proof of concept.](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-breeze-nkcl6?file=/src/App.js) The relevant portions are:

1. Instead of using the default `getToggleHideAllColumnsProps` props, you need to create your own onClick handler. `column` exposes a `toggleHidden` method which dictates the behavior when the user attempts to toggle that specific column. Somewhat frustratingly, even if you have implemented the `toggleHidden` method for a column, `getToggleHideAllColumnsProps` completely ignores it, and toggles its hidden status anyway.

```html
<div>
  <IndeterminateCheckbox 
    onClick={() => allColumns.forEach(c => c.id !== "firstName" && c.toggleHidden())} 
  /> 
  Toggle All
</div>
```

Luckily, it is a fairly simple function -- just iterate over your `columns` object and call `toggleHidden` on each. I included a check against calling it on the desired column anyway, for robustness, but you technically don't need to.

2. Somewhere, somehow, you need to define the `toggleHidden` function for the desired column. I did it in the render method for the checkboxes, but it works just the same if you do it elsewhere. When the `toggleHidden` function is defined for a column, it overrides the default behavior, as expected. So, you can just have an empty function that returns null, and this disables the ability to manually turn off that column.

```js
allColumns.map((column) => {
  if (column.id === "firstName") {
    column.toggleHidden = () => null;
  }
  return ( /* ...jsx... */ );
})
```